# I wanted to try Lubuntu but can't install guest additions

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, guest-additions

I get this error "can't find guest additions try installing them manually." Manually? What does that mean?

Why can't it find the guest addition it's right there in the optical drive. I see the files in the directory I right click on the .sh file, open with QTerminal nothing happens.

I downloaded a dab file with the guest additions installed. Windows host doesn't know what to do with a dab file. I can't connect linux to the internet or share a file without guest edition installed.

I've sudo this and apt get that and nothing but errors.

Why is it you can't do anything simple with Linux? What am I doing wrong other than barely understanding how to use Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't stated what release of Lubuntu you're using, so I've just used my own system.

I'd suggest opening the package manager (Muon) and doing a search for "virtualbox" which presented me with this screen

[image]

You'll note a number of virtualbox packages (extensions) that can be added (*that I don't have installed*).  The screen shows the results of my search.

Given I'm unsure what release you're using, nor what you want to do with it I'll assume you know which ones you're after.

Sorry I don't know what a *dab* file is.

Comment: FYI:  If it was me, I'd more likely open a terminal (`qterminal`) and `apt-cache search virtualbox-guest` ... but installation can be achieved in a number of ways.

Comment: The Muon Package Manager (provided by default on Lubuntu releases since 18.10, ie. all supported LXQt releases) page in the *stable* (21.04) manual can be found at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.2/muon.html ; you didn't provide release details; so if using a LTS release; change the word *stable* to say *lts* to view 20.04 LTS page.  I'm on the *development* cycle so my release is *impish* currently, but I'd expect the same looking results for any release; if you'd have specified a release I'd likely have used your release for the image & themes would likely be more default.

Comment: The version I'm using is 20.04  I tried Muon, in the list I found the "virtualbox guest additions.iso" hit the "not installed" hit the Marked for Installation on everything. Nothing but Fail. Most say x86 but I'm using a 64bit  Linux. I am at your mercy.

Comment: [UPDATE] Solved one problem by choosing the correct network adapter, my Ubuntu machine is now online.

Comment: [UPDATE] Did a full upgrade, restart, mounted the guest utils, I typed in the QTerminal: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms ~Restart, this worked without getting any Fails.

Comment: Just an FYI:  x86 isn't how Debian or Ubuntu refer to 32-bit *x86* so when you see x86 it usually is from upstream reference (ie. virtualbox indicates upstream is Oracle).  Both Debian & Ubuntu refer to all *x86 32-bit* as i386 (*regardless of it being i386, i486, i586 or what i386 now is i686*).  Sorry I didn't note your comment/question earlier.  Well done for getting it solved :)